# How to restructure data

Tags: go

I have a data of this format.

```
type PartsInfo struct {
   Parts map[string]struct {
       City     string `yaml:"city"`
       Services map[string]struct {
           Disabled bool `yaml:"disabled"`
       } `yaml:"services"`
   } `yaml:"parts"`
}
```

I want to convert it into this format:
`map[service]map[city][]parts` where only not disabled status services need to be added. I have been trying different combinations but cant get it just the way i want.

I guess one thing I am not sure of is the destination format. Should I be using the `map[service]map[city][]parts` format, or would a struct be better ? I do not see how, but I have been told before the best way to pass data in go is using structs, not maps. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want？

Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/N8mkD5pt1pD

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type PartitionData struct {
    Partitions map[string]Partition `yaml:"parts"`
}

type Partition struct {
    City     string `yaml:"city"`
    Services map[string]map[string]struct {
        Disabled bool `yaml:"disabled"`
    } `yaml:"services"`
}

var testData = PartitionData{
    Partitions: map[string]Partition{
        "partition1": {City: "c1", Services: map[string]map[string]struct{
            Disabled bool `yaml:"disabled"`
        }{
            "service1":{
                "1":{
                    Disabled: true,
                },
                "2":{
                    Disabled: true,
                },
            },
            "service2":{
                "1":{
                    Disabled: true,
                },
                "2":{
                    Disabled: true,
                },
            },
        }},
        "partition2": {City: "c1", Services: map[string]map[string]struct{
            Disabled bool `yaml:"disabled"`
        }{
            "service1":{
                "1":{
                    Disabled: true,
                },
                "2":{
                    Disabled: true,
                },
            },
            "service2":{
                "1":{
                    Disabled: true,
                },
                "2":{
                    Disabled: true,
                },
            },
        }},
    },
}

func main() {
    res:= make(map[string]map[string][]Partition)

    for _,part := range testData.Partitions{
        for serviceName :=range part.Services{
            if _,found := res[serviceName];!found {
                res[serviceName] = make(map[string][]Partition)
            }
            if _,found := res[serviceName][part.City];!found {
                res[serviceName][part.City] = make([]Partition,0)
            }
            res[serviceName][part.City] = append(res[serviceName][part.City], part)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(res)
}
```